# Drupal Registration Module Email Registrants tab

Tags: users

The character count for the subject field in email registrants is 40 characters and that is hard coded into the module.

I need some guidance for figuring out how to change that. I am not a hard core developer and do not know the best way to change that without going into the module code.

Can anyone help guid me to what could be done?

Thanks
Tim

EDIT***
I am in Drupal 7 Registration module 7.x-1.3.
Under Manage Registration/Email Registrants/ - there is a subject field. In the modules registration.forms.inc file on line 354 it the character limit size set to 40.

I am trying to figure out how to change it without editing the module code.

Thanks

Comment: Drupal 6? Are you mean subject field in User settings admin page? There's subject limited by 180 characters. Please explain

Comment: I have to use hook_form_alter in the Registration module.

Answer (score 0):

Not being a developer I had to figure this out using hook_form_alter. Too some digging and a little help.

```
function ecg_registration_form_registration_registrations_broadcast_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  //dpm($form);
  $form['subject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Subject'),
    '#description' => t('The subject of the message.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 80,
    '#maxlength' => 80,
  );
}
```

Hope that helps someone.